# FlutterLocalNotification plugin with java error to execute

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification

I'm trying to use the FlutterLocalNotification in my app and I'm getting errors when executing it. Can anyone know how can solve this? I try some similar questions but nothing works. (like included "  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'" inside the build.gradle)

```
class Notification extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Notification createState() => _Notification();
}
    class _Notification extends State<Notification> {
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterNotification =
          new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        var androidInitilize = new AndroidInitializationSettings("app_icon");
        var IOSinitialize = new IOSInitializationSettings();
        var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
            android: androidInitilize, iOS: IOSinitialize);
        flutterNotification = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
        flutterNotification.initialize(initializationSettings,
            onSelectNotification: notificationSelected('play'));
      }
    
      Future _showNotification() async {
        var androidDetails = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
            "Channel ID", "Details",
            importance: Importance.max);
        var IOSDetails = new IOSNotificationDetails();
        var generalNotificationDetails =
            new NotificationDetails(android: androidDetails, iOS: IOSDetails);
    
        await flutterNotification.show(
            0,
            "Title:",
            "body",
            generalNotificationDetails);
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement build
        throw UnimplementedError();
      }
    
      notificationSelected(String payload) async {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            content: Text("Notification : $payload"),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

class that calls the showNotification method:

```
class TriggeredNotification extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<dynamic, dynamic> _imageData;

  ImagePage(this._imageData);

  downloadImage() async {
    try {
      // Saved with this method.
      var imageId = await ImageDownloader.downloadImage(
          _imageData["images"]["fixed_height"]["url"],
          destination: AndroidDestinationType.directoryDownloads);
      if (imageId == null) {
        print("imageid : $imageId");
        return;
      } else {
        _Notification()._showNotification();
      }

      // Below is a method of obtaining saved image information.
      var fileName = await ImageDownloader.findName(imageId);
      var path = await ImageDownloader.findPath(imageId);
      var size = await ImageDownloader.findByteSize(imageId);
      var mimeType = await ImageDownloader.findMimeType(imageId);
      print(
          "filename: $fileName | path: $path | size: $size | mimetype: $mimeType");
    } on PlatformException catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_imageData['title']),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                downloadImage();
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.download))
        ],
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Image.network(_imageData["images"]["fixed_height"]["url"]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference, null, java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
    at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.setSmallIcon(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:300)
    at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.createNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:215)
    at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1024)
    at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1362)
    at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.onMethodCall(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1241)
    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:296)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:320)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$TsixYUB5E6FpKhMtCSQVHKE89gQ.run(Unknown Source:12)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
))
```

Comment: Make sure to follow the instructions here to add the icons: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#-android-setup

Answer (score 0):

For statement :  `var androidInitilize = new AndroidInitializationSettings("app_icon");`
it should be path to app_icon
see the following example, specifying launcher icon from mipmap folder of android app , you should write this

```
var androidInitilize  = new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher')
```

or if its from drawable folder of android app then

```
var androidInitilize  = new AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/app_icon')
```

let me know if its work you or not.

Comment: not work :/ still with this error "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference" at    await _Notification().flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show